# Parsing a text file and looking for a specific word

Tags: python, parsing

I'm trying to parse a text file to see if it contains a specific word. If the word exists, the word meaning with be printed out. For some reason my code doesn't return word_meaning. In the if/else statement it only prints out the else statement.

```
def parse_file_and_check_word(file_path, user_input):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            split_line = line.strip().split('-')
            if len(split_line) == 2:
                word, word_meaning = split_line
            if word == user_input:
                return word_meaning
        return None


t = input("Enter a word to look up")


word_meaning = parse_file_and_check_word("some_file.txt", t)
if word_meaning:
    print(word_meaning)
else:
    print('Word not found')
```

This is the contents of some_file.txt :

```
run - to move

Action Potential - 40mv

safe - not harmed

light - something bright
```

The output I'm trying to obtain is something like:

```
Enter a word: Action Potential
output: 40mv
```

Comment: You need to show an example (fragment) of the file you're reading and the expected output for a specific input. Note also that if the first line in your file does not contain two tokens then you'll get a NameError exception. Can you see why?

Comment: what does your file look like? My guess is: "word - explanation". This will make "word " and not "word".

Comment: DarkKnight, I've added the suggested changes. And I could not find the error you were referring to. Could you explain?

Comment: ph140, What do you mean, 'This will make "word " and not "word".'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file contains whitespace before and after the hyphen separator. Therefore you'll need to strip the individual tokens before comparing them. For example:

```
FILENAME = '/Volumes/G-Drive/some_file.txt'

def parse_file_and_check_word(file_path, user_input):
    with open(file_path) as data:
        while line := data.readline():
            q, *d = map(str.strip, line.split('-'))
            if d and q == user_input:
                return d[0]

print(parse_file_and_check_word(FILENAME, 'safe'))
print(parse_file_and_check_word(FILENAME, 'banana'))
print(parse_file_and_check_word(FILENAME, 'Action Potential'))
```

**Output:**

```
not harmed
None
40mv
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a intendation Error in if Statement.

Updated Code

```
def parse_file_and_check_word(file_path, user_input):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            split_line = line.strip().split('-')
            if len(split_line) == 2:
                word, word_meaning = split_line
                if word == user_input:
                    return word_meaning
    return None


t = input("Enter a word to look up")

word_meaning = parse_file_and_check_word("some_file.txt", t)
if word_meaning:
    print(word_meaning)
else:
    print('Word not found')
```

Comment: I indented the return None statement and it's still saying the same thing.

Comment: You need to intent if statement also

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. Could you perhaps recreate the program that I am trying to use and show me what output you got?